# Using dismax to search for multiword indexed terms

Tags: java, solr, lucene, dismax

My solr schema is the following ( only important parts):

```
<fieldType name="bagofwords_expertfinding" class="solr.TextField"    positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <!-- remove letters repeated more than two times -->
    <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="stopwords_en.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true"
            />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="^[0-9-/_,\.]+$" replacement="" replace="all"/>
    <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="^.*(([aA-zZ])\\2)\\2+.*$" replacement=""/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="3" max="100"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="stopwords_en.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true"
            />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="^[0-9-/_,\.]+$" replacement="" replace="all"/> 
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="3" max="100"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
<fieldType name="namedentities_expertfinding" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <!-- remove letters repeated more than two times -->
    <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="\s," replacement=","/>
    <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern=",\s" replacement=","/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="," />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="stopwords_en.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true"
            />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="^[0-9-/_,\.]+$" replacement="" replace="all"/> 
    <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="3" max="100"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

In namedentities i have indexed multiword terms like: "diego alberto milito","diego armando maradona". I'm trying to search in both fields boosting them differently with a dismax query.

But trying with this query:
    localhost:8080/solr/select/?q="diego armando maradona"&defType=dismax&qf=namedentities^100 bagofwords^1&fl=*,score&debugQuery=true&mm=0

solr doesn't find nothing. Maybe i don't understand the correct use of " symbol.

I don't understand also given this from solr wiki:

"In Solr 1.4 and prior, you should basically set mm=0 if you want the equivilent of q.op=OR, and mm=100% if you want the equivilent of q.op=AND. In 3.x and trunk the default value of mm is dictated by the q.op param (q.op=AND => mm=100%; q.op=OR => mm=0%). Keep in mind the default operator is effected by your schema.xml  entry. In older versions of Solr the default value is 100% (all clauses must match)"

and given that in my schema the defaultOperator is OR why, without setting mm=0, i obtain a default mm value of 100.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The output of the debug version of the parsed query would also be useful. I suspect that since you tokenize the field, your exact search won't match - as neither of the entries are the string you're searching for when you enclose it in quotes.

Comment: thanks. I've finally discover that the quotes doesn't mean exact match but looking for a phrase: consecutive string so i changed my schema analyzer. But there's not a way to deal with multiword tokens... so i'm putting in the index single words and searching for phrases

Answer (score 0):

Having the quotes around the query string above is forcing a phrase query. This means only exact matches are considered. Remove them, replacing with parens, and experiment with the pf and pf2 and pf3 parameters to boost longer matching phrases.